# How to set kubernetes tolerations to those without taints by default

Tags: kubernetes, helm3

I am wondering if there is a way to use tolerations but allow pods to schedule on nodes without any taints by default.
I have read https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/
and was considering using an empty key with operator Exists but this means it will tolerate everything and I would like to avoid the tainted nodes by default.

Comment: you can achieve it without putting any tolerations at all right ?

Comment: I am trying to set certain pods on a tainted node group and others in a node group without any taints by reusing the same chart for both cases